# Opencart admin panel new category creating premission issue

Tags: php, opencart

I'm new in opencart and php. I'm trying to create custom form in admin panel and have premission problem

[problem when I press on text catridge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uvltc.png)

already for now i put in view/template/common/menu.tpl

```
<li><a href="<?php echo $catridge; ?>"><?php echo $text_catridge; ?></a></li>
```

Also i put in admin/controller/common/menu.php

```
$data['text_catridge']= $this ->language->get('text_catridge');
```

How to make that premission and what next ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to navigate to `user groups` where you will select the user group you belong to. From there you will see `access permission` & `modify permission`. you will have to make sure that relevant items are ticked accordingly.
After ticking the items navigate back to the page and it should be accessible.